# File Permission Windows

Tags: file-permissions

I've got a question about file permission in Windows.
I'd like to have a folder in which I have some pictures and the user should not be allowed to modify this file. The pictures cannot be deleted nor can anybody copy anything from another file to that specific file. They do have to be capable of copying pictures to other files though. How do I do this? I've looked under the security tab and I've gone though file permissions like read only, but none of them seems to fit my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Turn off inherit permissions to erase all permissions (also for the folder Owner):

- Create a new folder
- Right click on your newly created folder and select **Properties**
- Switch to the **Security** tab in the top
- Click on the **Advanced** button in the bottom, then the **Change Permissions...** button
- Uncheck this box: *Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent*
- A warning will pop up, confirm the change by clicking **Remove**, then click on **OK** to close the dialog box. (Another warning will pop up, click Yes to confirm)
- Click OK again
- Now you should be back in the folder properties window at the Security tab, click on the **Edit** button, then the **Add** button. Type **everyone** in the dialog box and then **OK** to add the user. *Everyone* will automatically be added with the correct permissions. Click **OK** to close the dialog then **OK** again to close the folder property window.

If you try to make changes to the folder now, you won't have access.

Please note, you are still the **Owner** of this folder, so if you regret what you just did, you can add yourself in the permission field so you may Write/Modify the folder.

Just tested to make sure and it works fine, let me know if you experience any problems.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on how I can achieve this?

Comment: @Ramhound that's only because his question was unclear. My rep is too low to comment on his question, else I would. Please see updated post

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question and thank you very much for your time. I have done everything you described but I'm still capable of deleting documents in my file and that's not supossed to happen?

Comment: Maxim: That's because you're the Owner of the folder. As I mentioned, there must always be 1 folder Owner. If you really want nobody to be able to modify this folder, then you must manually create a new user on your machine, then transfer the ownership of the folder to this user. I'll update the answer again to show you how you can transfer ownership of folder :) Ok Ramhound, I'll keep that in mind for any other questions.

Comment: Sorry for double post (cant edit prev comment), but the new updated answer should solve your issue, Maxim. Let me know if you have any troubles